# Facebook Linter is Returning Inconsistant Results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When I run my url, http://whatthefuckshouldidrinktonight.com , through the Facebook Linter, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug , I get three different results at random.

First is an error of "Too many redirects" accompanied by partially correct open graph info

Second is an error of "Missing Required Property" for the three required properties, og:url, og:type, og:title. However, the "Raw Open Graph Information" contains all three, and is correct.

and Third the linter returns with no errors and the correct open graph information.

Because it's returning these results seemingly at random, I have no idea where to start in terms of looking for the problem. Has anyone else experienced anything similar?

Comment: I upvoted this since I have the same problem.  I think its just facebook not working properly, unfortunately.  I am having the same issue I have created two static pages and I continue to refresh the object debugger and receive inconsistent results, sometimes the tags are read sometimes they are not.  The same thing happens in production with the like buttons.  Sometimes only the url is used and sometimes the title / url / description etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your URL through the linter. Here is what I see:

Your image does not show up right (not a big issue), it warns about locale, but nothing other than warnings. Img: http://cl.ly/Ar9j

However, it is a little interesting when looking at the og:url field. This seems like it should not go to a specific drink for the homepage. Also, clicking that link leads to a 500 error (image: http://cl.ly/Aqxy).

That looks like you site provides a random drink when the homepage is hit. I get a 500 when I visit the main site, which may cause FB issues as well.

I also got the linter to switch between states - sometimes it was good, sometimes it failed. I would double check everything. Clicking the debug button over and over gave me varying errors.

I dont think that this is a bug in the linter. I think that there is something goofy with a few pages in your app.